# How to convert ISOString to date format dd/mm/yyyy using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, datetime

I want to change the date to the format `dd/mm/yyyy` but I did not succeed. I tried something like this:

```
<span class="postupdate">2015-03-01T14:28:28Z</span>
```

```js
$(function(){
    var d = $(".postupdate").html();
    var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
    d.html(n);
});
```

but I do not know how to to change the date it with javascript or jquery. whether to use a regex to change that date?
Can someone help me?

Comment: let me konw if answer is usefyul @Dyana Putry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to parsing values of date. In bottom code, i used regex in [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to parsing day, month, year of date.

```
$(".postupdate").text().match(/([^T]+)/)[0].split("-").reverse().join("/");
```

In your case, you can use this code:

```js
$("span").text(function(i, text){
    return text.match(/([^T]+)/)[0].split("-").reverse().join("/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="postupdate">2015-03-01T14:28:28Z</span>
```

Comment: I've tried and succeeded 100% perfect than I wanted. Thank you very much already very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
 var d = $(".postupdate").html();
var date=new Date(d);
```

Then using [X-Class](https://github.com/abdennour/xclass) package:

```
date.format('dd/mm/yyyy');
 // 01/03/2015
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/vg5zjjyg/5/)

Comment: Does this require any external file?

Comment: yes .. this is part of `x-class` node package :  `<script src="https://rawgit.com/abdennour/xclass/master/node_modules/x-date/index.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: But user may not be using node and this question is not tagged with node

Comment: IT can be used without node , just add the following in ur HTML  :  `<script src="https://rawgit.com/abdennour/xclass/master/node_modules/x-date/index.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>  `

Comment: Wow cool, was very helpful and useful for my future. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: @DyanaPutry : if so, put my answer as the resolved answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Option:1

Use `getDate`,`getMonth` & `getYear` method to get the date , month & year from the date. Use [**conditional**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator to form the date format.

`+1`(not unary plus) is used with `getMonth` since it starts with 0,

```
var date=new Date('2015-03-01T14:28:28Z');
var _dd = "";
var _mm="";
var _yy = date.getFullYear();

date.getDate() <10 ? (_dd='0'+date.getDate()):(_dd=date.getDate());
(date.getMonth()+1) <10?(_mm='0'+(date.getMonth()+1)):(_mm = date.getDate()+1);
var _m = _dd + '/' +_mm+ '/' +_yy;
document.write('<pre>'+_m+'</pre>')
```

[**Option 1 JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3m1gx10y/2/)

## Option:2

Using [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) & [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break a split a string and create an array.
Then use it's index of the array to change the format

```
var getDate = "2015-03-01T14:28:28Z".slice(0, 10).split('-'); //create an array
var _date =getDate[1] +'/'+ getDate[2] +'/'+ getDate[0];
document.write('<pre>'+_date+'</pre>')
```

[**Option 2 JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3m1gx10y/3/)

Comment: I'm really excited to see what you explained to me. This is useful for me, thanks for help